# Sinatra indent partial erb at statement

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is it a way to make partials in sinatra be indented at the level where I call it?

Example

```
<body>
    <div>
        <%= partial :"mypartial" %>
    </div>
</body>
```

Results in

```
<body>
    <div>
<div id="i am defined in mypartial">
    //etc
</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I want

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="i am defined in mypartial">
            //etc
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is possible if I indent the partial currectly, but that makes it hard to work with. I want the partial to be starting indentation all the way to the left(in the source file).

Maybe there is some kind of post processor that can format that html for me?
This is for a project that is not going public, but it's important that internal users can read the generated html easily. Including correct indentation.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to your _question_ but whether I find one or not a solution to your _problem_ might be to mark the open and close of significant section with `<!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION -->` and `<!-- END NAVIGATION -->` and the like. Those kind of comments can be very useful even with proper indentation.

Comment: I'm having a hard time duplicating your problem. In a Sinatra app I have the indentation appears as expected with the `<%= yield %>` erb. Is there any additional info you can offer?

Comment: i'm experiencing the same issue